# Splash screen for watchkit in swift

Tags: swift, splash-screen, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacecontroller

I would like to implement a splash screen for my watch application. After a long check, i haven come to realize there is not a way as for phone and tablet such launchscreen.xib or launch image in info.plist for watch

To implement splash screen, i made a new starting interface, which will only appear when application starts. To do that

for life cycle i have checked [this blog](http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/118262770484/watchkit-controller-life-cycle)

after that in willActivate() func i have implemented

```
    if first {
        first = false
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }else{
        first = true
        self.popController()
    }
```

and my update func

```
func update() {
    self.pushControllerWithName("someListsController", context: nil)
}
```

my point is; i want this interface to show only when application starts, and when returning this interface , application to end.

Comment: [this post](https://medium.com/@benjones_design/design-for-the-apple-watch-the-sequel-6565b4c07e6a) is telling me not to use splash screen since user just want spend seconds to look their watch(or use my app), so 1-2 seconds to look splash screen will make them frustrated. Yet, i need to implement splash screen.

Comment: It is better to prevent adding splash screens to your apps, as Apple says in the documentations and WWDC session videos.